# Connect Current_User Account to users Facebook & Twitter Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, twitter-oauth, facebook-oauth

**I've been searching for a while on how to simply connect a Current_User Account to their Twitter or Facebook account.**

I don't want users to login with Twitter or Facebook, I just want them to be able to connect to their Twitter/Facebook account so they can feed their User Activity to either Facebook or Twitter. **(Similar to how Twitter/Tumblr do it with Facebook)**

I know I need to use Oauth to connect to either Facebook/Twitter, but I do not know how to store the token or user_id from the third party site.

**I have registered my App with both Facebook & Twitter, but I do not know what else to do to accomplish this.**

```
**This is my Current User Database**

class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.string :bio
      t.string :username, unique: true

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index "users", ["username"], :name => "index_users_on_username", :unique => true
  end
end
```

New to Rails Please Help...

Comment: Let me make clear: you want to post to Facebook as a user and you want to do it in backend, not from dialog on website?

Comment: oh no. i would like current users in my rails app, to feed their Dailypost from my current app to their profile if they decide to connect to their facebook account. (similar to what twitter/tumblr do with Facebook) @MichaelSzyndel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter what attribute name you give it.  Just store it in your users table as something and pass it to fb/twitter (as per their API documentation) during your request to these sites. Maybe fb_token and twitter_token?

If this doesn't answer your question please elaborate as it is not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Yea this is what I am searching for....would you happen to know of a tutorial or any blogs that can guide me on how to get this started. Do i need omniauth? @LadyLinx

Comment: @LadyLinx http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17519700/connect-users-to-their-twitter-accounts-rails-app I have reposted a new question with further detail. Please Help :)

Comment: Temboo has a good support article that walks step-by-step through the OAuth process, at http://support.temboo.com/entries/24131857-Using-OAuth-Choreos -- this example is about Facebook, but the Temboo SDK (free account required) provides a standardized mechanism for completing the OAuth handshake with many APIs including Facebook and Twitter.